# Adobe AIR nativeProcess support profile

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am working on a project which requires nativeProcess support. For this purpose, I choose the `extendedDesktop` profile in AIR settings (Flash cs6). But when I publish the AIR executable, an error pops up saying: 
"*Descriptor must support one of the following profiles: desktop, mobileDevice, extendedMobileDevice, tv, mobileDeviceBase*".
 If I add both the `Desktop` and the `extendedDesktop` profile support to the app then `nativeProcess.isSupported()` returns false. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question:

It turns out you have to specify the profiles in a certain order. If you want to support `Desktop` profile and have `ExtendedDesktop` profile capabilities (eg. `nativeProcess`) you have to specify it in your application's .xml file like this:

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop desktop</supportedProfiles>
```

Also, when publishing, make sure to choose *Output as: Windows Installer* or otherwise you won't get `nativeProcess` support when you run the installed app.

Further reading: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/699165

Comment: In fact, both -target bundle and -target native will produce an executable which can run native processes.

Comment: That might have changed in recent versions of Flash, although I cannot be certain. I do distinctly remember that native was the only target that resulted in nativeProcess.isSupported()  returning true.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: < supportedProfiles > extendedDesktop desktop < / supportedProfiles > also note that the compiler argument must be set as well in run/debug settings -> command line arguments: -profile extendedDesktop

Comment: Thank you. Where is "command line arguments:" located in Flash cs6 ?

Comment: Tried just now, unfortunately it didn't work. When I installed the compiled AIR package, nativeProcess.isSupported() still outputted false

Comment: @BotMaster Bad answer. astralmaster found himself the solution. Voted down.